# Birkhoff – von Neumann for "$k$-stochastic matrices"

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-geometry, stochastic-matrices

Recall that a *doubly-stochastic matrix* is a square matrix with non-negative elements such the sum of the elements in every row, as well as in every column, is $1$. The set of doubly-stochastic matrices is described by the [Birkhoff – von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix). For the matrices of prime order $p\ge 3$, this theorem can be interpreted to describe the set of all functions $w\colon\mathbb F_p^2\to\mathbb R^+$ such that for some pair of fixed directions in $\mathbb F_p^2$, every line $l$ in any of these directions gets its exact share of the total mass of $w$:
  $$ \sum_{x\in l} w(x) = \frac1p\,\sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p^2 } w(x). \tag{$*$} $$

Let's say that *a line $l\in\mathbb F_p^2$ is even* if it satisfies ($*$), and that *a direction in $\mathbb F_p^2$ is even* if all $p$ lines in this directions are even. Suppose that, instead of just two even directions (as in the Birkhoff – von Neumann theorem), there are $k\ge 3$ even directions. Intuitively, one can expect much more structure in this case.

> For a prime $p$ and integer $3\le k\le p$, what is the set of all functions  $w\colon\mathbb F_p^2\to\mathbb R^+$ possessing at least $k$ even directions?

In particular, isn't this set of functions the matching polytope of some graph?

Comment: The naive conjecture is that it's given by the convex hull of special permutation matrices (those that have a 1 in every line paralel to any of the given directions). Is this known to be false?

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: this is hardly the case; at least, not for large values of $k$. For $k>p/2$, for instance, there do not exist any permutation matrices with $k$ even directions.

Comment: Isn't the indicator function of an arbitrary line that's not parallel to any of our directions always such a permutation?

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: Right, but this is the only exception.

Comment: Another equivalent way of phrasing my conjecture is that the vertices of this polytope (assuming we normalize the sum to 1 on each direction) are all lattice points.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: I can neither prove nor disprove your conjecture, but if true,
it implies that for $k>p/2$, every $k$-stochastic matrix is a convex
combination of "linear matrices". That is, every function $w\colon\mathbb
F_p^2\to\mathbb R^+$ with $(p+1)/2$ or more even directions is a convex
combination of the indicator functions of lines.

Comment: Examples are given by orthogonal arrays. For example, consider $k=3$ and the $3\times 3$ square shown at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square .  Choose any $A,B,C$ summing to 1.  Then as well as the rows and columns each summing to 1, the positions containing $\alpha$ sum to 1 and similarly for $\beta$ and $\gamma$.  A projective plane will provide $p-1$ separate directions, such as the example for $p=5$ given in the section "Mutually orthogonal Latin squares".  I suspect these examples are not representative of all examples.

Comment: Note to my previous comment: Each of these examples are the convex hulls of some set of permutation matrices.  For example, the permutation matrices $A=1$, $B=1$ and $C=1$ in the first case.